# Does android string.xml support any other form of xml?

Tags: android, arrays, xml

I know that a string array like this is supported by android easily:

```
<string-array name="tabs_names"> 
    <item>My Tab 1</item> 
    <item>My Tab 2</item>
</string-array>
```

But, I have a different type of xml. Will  it be supported by andorid? If yes, how?

```
<sura index="114" name="الناس">
    <aya index="1" text="قُلْ أَعُوذُ بِرَبِّ النَّاسِ" bismillah="بِسْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَنِ الرَّحِيمِ" />
    <aya index="2" text="مَلِكِ النَّاسِ" />
    <aya index="3" text="إِلَهِ النَّاسِ" />
    <aya index="4" text="مِن شَرِّ الْوَسْوَاسِ الْخَنَّاسِ" />
    <aya index="5" text="الَّذِي يُوَسْوِسُ فِي صُدُورِ النَّاسِ" />
    <aya index="6" text="مِنَ الْجِنَّةِ وَالنَّاسِ" />
</sura>
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: It will be a valid xml file but Android uses specific keywords to build its xml resources so this will not work.

Comment: @DavidArgyleThacker So, there is no way to use this in android. Should  I edit it to correct format?

Comment: One option would be to create XSLT for preprocessing the existing xml into android supported format

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is a valid piece of xml code, it will not be able to be used with the Android resource structure. Android has specific tags and keywords that it looks for to build xml resources.

For a list of available String formats you can refer to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) guide on providing String resources for Android.

It will be necessary to convert any xml files you have to the first format you listed, which is the Android supported way for handling String arrays.

Comment: @DA Thacker.. Can't we have any way to parse it properly? Any suggestions?

Comment: Not that I am aware of because this would have to take place prior to compiling your source code. You could possibly find a way to use code generation to translate your existing xml files to the Android supported, resource format.